# I can't figure out whats wrong with my java tictactoe

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

It keeps spitting out "you can pick that space its already been taken and it seems like it's ignoring all the other if statements. I've been tinkering at this for a couple hours and I don't know how to fix it.

```
public class tictactoegame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j = 0;

        System.out.println("");
        char a = ('a');
        char b = ('b');
        char c = ('c');
        char d = ('d');
        char e = ('e');
        char f = ('f');
        char g = ('g');
        char h = ('h');
        char i = ('i');

        
        
        String gameboard = ("    1  2  3\n1   "+a+"| "+b+ " | "+c+"\n   - - - - -"+"\n2   "+d+"| "+e+ " | "+f+"\n   - - - - -"+"\n3   "+g+"| "+h+ " | "+i+"\n   - - - - -");
        System.out.println(gameboard);
        a = (' ');
        b = (' ');
        c = (' ');
        d = (' ');
        e = (' ');
        f = (' ');
        g = (' ');
        h = (' ');
        i = (' ');


        


        System.out.println();

        
        while (j < 9){
            int x = IO.inputInt("What is your x value");
            int y = IO.inputInt("What is your y value");
                
            //For X

            if (j%2 == 0){
                System.out.println("\n Invalid attempt, try again");
            }
            else if (x == 1 && y == 1 && a != 'X' && a != 'O' ){
                a = ('X');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 1 && y == 2 && b != 'X' && b != 'O' ){
                b = ('X');
                j++;
            } 
            else if (x == 1 && y == 3 && c != 'X' && c != 'O' ){
                c = ('X');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 2 && y == 1  && d != 'X' && d != 'O' ){
                d = ('X');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 2 && y == 2  && e != 'X' && e != 'O' ){
                e = ('X');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 2 && y == 3  && f != 'X' && f != 'O' ){
                f = ('X');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 3 && y == 1 && g != 'X' && g != 'O' ){
                g = ('X');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 3 && y == 2  && h != 'X' && h != 'O' ){
                h = ('X');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 3 && y == 3  && i != 'X' && i != 'O' ){
                i = ('X');
                j++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("you cant pick that space its already been taken");}

            //For O
            
            if (j%2 != 0){
                System.out.println("\n Invalid attempt, try again");
            }
            else if (x == 1 && y == 1  && a != 'X' && a != 'O' ){
                a = ('O');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 1 && y == 2  && b != 'X' && b != 'O' ){
                b = ('O');
                j++;
            } 
            else if (x == 1 && y == 3  && c != 'X' && c != 'O' ){
                c = ('O');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 2 && y == 1 && d != 'X' && d != 'O' ){
                d = ('O');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 2 && y == 2 && e != 'X' && e != 'O' ){
                e = ('O');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 2 && y == 3 && f != 'X' && f != 'O' ){
                f = ('O');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 3 && y == 1 && g != 'X' && g != 'O' ){
                g = ('O');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 3 && y == 2 && h != 'X' && h != 'O' ){
                h = ('O');
                j++;
            }
            else if (x == 3 && y == 3 && i != 'X' && i != 'O' ){
                i = ('O');
                j++;

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("you cant pick that space its already been taken");}
            
            if (a == 'X') {
                if (b == 'X') {
                    if (c == 'X') {
                        System.out.println("X wins!!!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
             if (d == 'X') {
                if (e == 'X') {
                    if (f == 'X') {
                        System.out.println("X wins!!!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
              if (g == 'X') {
                if (h == 'X') {
                    if (i == 'X') {
                        System.out.println("X wins!!!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
               if (a == 'X') {
                if (e == 'X') {
                    if (f == 'X') {
                        System.out.println("X wins!!!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
                if (a == 'X') {
                    if (d == 'X') {
                        if (g == 'X') {
                            System.out.println("X wins!!!");
                            System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
                if (b == 'X') {
                    if (e == 'X') {
                        if (h == 'X') {
                            System.out.println("X wins!!!");
                            System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
                if (c == 'X') {
                    if (f == 'X') {
                        if (i == 'X') {
                            System.out.println("X wins!!!");
                            System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
                if (c == 'X') {
                    if (e == 'X') {
                        if (g == 'X') {
                            System.out.println("X wins!!!");
                            System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }

            //O

            if (a == 'O') {
                if (b == 'O') {
                    if (c == 'O') {
                        System.out.println("O wins!!!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
             if (d == 'O') {
                if (e == 'O') {
                    if (f == 'O') {
                        System.out.println("O wins!!!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
              if (g == 'O') {
                if (h == 'O') {
                    if (i == 'O') {
                        System.out.println("O wins!!!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
               if (a == 'O') {
                if (e == 'O') {
                    if (f == 'O') {
                        System.out.println("O wins!!!");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
                if (a == 'O') {
                    if (d == 'O') {
                        if (g == 'O') {
                            System.out.println("O wins!!!");
                            System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
                if (b == 'O') {
                    if (e == 'O') {
                        if (h == 'O') {
                            System.out.println("O wins!!!");
                            System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
                if (c == 'O') {
                    if (f == 'O') {
                        if (i == 'O') {
                            System.out.println("O wins!!!");
                            System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
                if (c == 'O') {
                    if (e == 'O') {
                        if (g == 'O') {
                            System.out.println("O wins!!!");
                            System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }            
            if (j == 9 && a != ' '&& b != ' '&& c != ' '&& d != ' '&& e != ' ' && f != ' '&& g != ' '&& h != ' '&& i != ' '){
                System.out.println("Tie Game");
                System.exit(1);

            }


            System.out.println(gameboard);
    
        }}




    }
```

The program should let me change the values of a-i and display it on the game board instead it just spits out the else statement.

Comment: So have you tried [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code? Stack Overflow requires that you identify the source of your problem, otherwise, there's no way to ask any sort of meaningful and specific question, which is kind of important for a Q&A site.

Comment: To be honest, besides the code, you’d better give the specific rules for dealing with the problem or the “playstyle” of this “game”, otherwise few people will have the patience to read this kind of code, at least I won’t read it

Comment: Is there any possibility that the problem is in the `IO.inputInt` method, which you haven't shown?

Comment: When `if (j%2 == 0){` is `true`,  you should contain the actions within this block, same for `if (j%2 != 0){`

Comment: Incidentally, one problem that should be easy to fix is that you're never changing the value of the `gameboard` variable inside the loop, so no matter what happens with `a, b, c ...`, the board will always be printed the same.

Comment: Also, `j` doesn't need to be incremented in each if statement, it should increment AFTER all the if statements have run

Comment: You're trying to deal with both X's turn and O's turn in the same iteration of the loop.  Within each iteration, you're prompting X for the co-ordinates of their turn; but you're never prompting O.  Then O's turn ends up being the same as X's turn, which fails; but then the code can never get back on track, because next time through the loop, you still don't ask O for their co-ordinates.  So the same error happens again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to learn how to desk check your code (sit down if a piece of paper and a pen and walk through you code writing down the state)

For example, let's look at...

```
if (j % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("\n Invalid attempt, try again");
} else if (x == 1 && y == 1 && a != 'X' && a != 'O') {
    a = ('X');
    j++;
} else if (x == 1 && y == 2 && b != 'X' && b != 'O') {
    b = ('X');
    j++;
} else if (x == 1 && y == 3 && c != 'X' && c != 'O') {
    c = ('X');
    j++;
} else if (x == 2 && y == 1 && d != 'X' && d != 'O') {
    d = ('X');
    j++;
} else if (x == 2 && y == 2 && e != 'X' && e != 'O') {
    e = ('X');
    j++;
} else if (x == 2 && y == 3 && f != 'X' && f != 'O') {
    f = ('X');
    j++;
} else if (x == 3 && y == 1 && g != 'X' && g != 'O') {
    g = ('X');
    j++;
} else if (x == 3 && y == 2 && h != 'X' && h != 'O') {
    h = ('X');
    j++;
} else if (x == 3 && y == 3 && i != 'X' && i != 'O') {
    i = ('X');
    j++;
} else {
    System.out.println("you cant pick that space its already been taken");
}

//For O
if (j % 2 != 0) {
    System.out.println("\n Invalid attempt, try again");
} else if (x == 1 && y == 1 && a != 'X' && a != 'O') {
    a = ('O');
    j++;
} else if (x == 1 && y == 2 && b != 'X' && b != 'O') {
    b = ('O');
    j++;
} else if (x == 1 && y == 3 && c != 'X' && c != 'O') {
    c = ('O');
    j++;
} else if (x == 2 && y == 1 && d != 'X' && d != 'O') {
    d = ('O');
    j++;
} else if (x == 2 && y == 2 && e != 'X' && e != 'O') {
    e = ('O');
    j++;
} else if (x == 2 && y == 3 && f != 'X' && f != 'O') {
    f = ('O');
    j++;
} else if (x == 3 && y == 1 && g != 'X' && g != 'O') {
    g = ('O');
    j++;
} else if (x == 3 && y == 2 && h != 'X' && h != 'O') {
    h = ('O');
    j++;
} else if (x == 3 && y == 3 && i != 'X' && i != 'O') {
    i = ('O');
    j++;

} else {
    System.out.println("you cant pick that space its already been taken");
}
```

This looks okay, but, let's step through it, first loop...

- `j == 0`
- `x` and `y` are `1`
- `(j % 2 == 0)` is `true`, print `"Invalid attempt, try again"`
- `(j % 2 != 0)` is `false`
- `(x == 1 && y == 1 && a != 'X' && a != 'O')` is `true`, set `a` to `'O'`, increment `j` by one (`j` == `1`)

Next loop...

- `j == 1`
- `x` is `1`, `y` is `2`
- `(j % 2 == 0)` is `false`
- `(x == 1 && y == 2 && b != 'X' && b != 'O')` is `true`, set `b` to `'X'`, increment `j` by one (`j` == `2`!!)
- `(j % 2 != 0)` is `false`
- `(x == 1 && y == 2 && b != 'X' && b != 'O')` is `false`!!
- Print `"you cant pick that space its already been taken"`

And this is now your core issue.  Incrementing `j` inside each `if` statement will cause the next block to think it is it's turn.

What you could do is use a single `if-elseif-else` block, but, based on the value of `j`, set a `player` character, for example...

```
char player = 'X';
while (j < 9) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
        player = 'X';
    } else {
        player = 'O';
    }

    System.out.println("Current player: " + player);
    System.out.println("What is your x value");
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your y value");
    int y = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    if (x == 1 && y == 1 && a != 'X' && a != 'O') {
        a = player;
        j++;
    } else if (x == 1 && y == 2 && b != 'X' && b != 'O') {
        b = player;
        j++;
    } else if (x == 1 && y == 3 && c != 'X' && c != 'O') {
        c = player;
        j++;
    } else if (x == 2 && y == 1 && d != 'X' && d != 'O') {
        d = player;
        j++;
    } else if (x == 2 && y == 2 && e != 'X' && e != 'O') {
        e = player;
        j++;
    } else if (x == 2 && y == 3 && f != 'X' && f != 'O') {
        f = player;
        j++;
    } else if (x == 3 && y == 1 && g != 'X' && g != 'O') {
        g = player;
        j++;
    } else if (x == 3 && y == 2 && h != 'X' && h != 'O') {
        h = player;
        j++;
    } else if (x == 3 && y == 3 && i != 'X' && i != 'O') {
        i = player;
        j++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("A you cant pick that space its already been taken");
    }
```

*(please note, I replaced your `IO` class for `Scanner` as `IO` is not a standard Java library class)*

Oh and at the end of that, you need to update the `gameboard`

```
gameboard = ("    1  2  3\n1   " + a + "| " + b + " | " + c + "\n   - - - - -" + "\n2   " + d + "| " + e + " | " + f + "\n   - - - - -" + "\n3   " + g + "| " + h + " | " + i + "\n   - - - - -");
```

otherwise it will never change